# iOS App Review Fail - iPad with iOS 7.1 crashes on Launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, crash, appstore-approval

I have some trouble to review my App for the App Store. Thats not my first App but I just cant get the Error.

The App works on Real Device (iPhone 5S) without any exceptions. I don't have an iPad, but on Simulator it works perfectly.

STEPS: 
1. App Launches with Launcher Image
2. App SHOULD create / open SQLite3 Database and populate a `UITableView` from it. As i said - works perfectly on iPhone but crashes directly after Launch-Screens on iPad.

**EDIT:::
- I found at the Targets Position the following: 
"Patientenratgeber" 
"PatientenratgeberTests" 
If I build for the first one - no errors 
If I build the second - error 
Do I need this second Build Target? How can i delete it without causing new problems?**

Some ideas why this happens?

This is my Crash-Report:

```
{"bundleID":"Patientenratgeber","app_name":"Patientenratgeber","bug_type":"109","name":"Patientenratgeber","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1 (11D167)","version":"1.0 (1.0)"} Incident Identifier: D72511CB-A5EA-4C6A-A535-DD1FB46BC2E5 CrashReporter Key:   4f2c8fa05c83e9d455c232dbd2fa63e852283d0e Hardware Model:      xxx Process:             Patientenratgeber [1324] Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/DF803017-609F-498A-8C5C-56FB17B4F581/Patientenratgeber.app/Patientenratgeber Identifier:          Patientenratgeber Version:             1.0 (1.0) Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native) Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-05-01 10:53:37.785 -0700 OS Version:         iOS 7.1 (11D167) Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000005 Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0 Crashed: 0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018ee0c0b0 objc_retain + 16 1   UIKit                           0x00000001853e466c
-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 572 2   UIKit                          0x00000001853e43f0 -[UIViewController view] + 28 3   UIKit              0x0000000185465af0 -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 436 4   UIKit          0x0000000185463f48 -[UIWindow
_setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:]
+ 1216 5   UIKit                            0x0000000185463a00 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 124 6   UIKit                             0x00000001853e6450 -[UIWindow
_updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400 7   UIKit                          0x000000018546302c -[UIViewController
_tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 188 8   UIKit                          0x00000001853eb95c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 508 9   UIKit                          0x00000001853e8d74 -[UIWindow
_setHidden:forced:] + 288 10  UIKit                             0x000000018545b838 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 64 11  UIKit         0x0000000185458144 -[UIApplication
_callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 2136 12  UIKit                             0x00000001854519e8 -[UIApplication
_runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 768 13  UIKit                          0x00000001853e58c8 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3312 14  UIKit                          0x00000001853e4acc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 100 15  UIKit          0x0000000185451040 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 668 16  GraphicsServices                 0x0000000187fb7500 _PurpleEventCallback
+ 672 17  GraphicsServices                  0x0000000187fb702c PurpleEventCallback + 44 18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001823da88c
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52 19  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001823da7ec __CFRunLoopDoSource1
+ 440 20  CoreFoundation                    0x00000001823d8a10 __CFRunLoopRun + 1616 21  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001823196cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448 22  UIKit                 0x00000001854501c4 -[UIApplication _run] + 780 23  UIKit                0x000000018544afd8 UIApplicationMain + 1152 24  Patientenratgeber       0x000000010005d400 main (main.m:16) 25  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018f3e7a9c start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f4c9aa8 kevent64 + 8 1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f3cd998
_dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018f4e2e74
__workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x000000018f561548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018f4e2e74
__workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x000000018f561548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000005   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x00000000ffffffff   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x000000018f15af34   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x2b00950554ab6cf2  x10: 0x000000016fda89e2  x11: 0x0000000192b24c3f    x12: 0x0000000000000018 x13: 0x0000000000060000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000000    x16: 0x000000018ee0d8cc  x17: 0x0000000100064018 x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000015d510c50    x20: 0x0000000170248760  x21: 0x0000000185ab3f08  x22: 0x0000000185adb64c  x23: 0x0000000185ad2516    x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000178062240  x26: 0x000000019232e098  x27: 0x0000000000000001   x28: 0x0000000000000003  fp: 0x000000016fda8b70   lr: 0x000000010005d56c
    sp: 0x000000016fda8b50   pc: 0x000000018ee0c0b0 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
```

Comment: Show us some code ? Your app del and/or where you create the tableview etc ? Is there a crash message when you run on device ?

Comment: It was because SQLite3 Database was closed and another Function tried to access it after closing it again. Small things could fast get big ;-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug your code by enabling NSZombieEnabled flag. 
Take a look at the images below and follow the steps.

[image: Select Edit Scheme]

[image: check NSZombieEnabled]

Comment: Hey iLearner, I'll try it now and keep you informed if it helped me out =)

Comment: @RabidaInternetagentur ya sure

Comment: I activated zombies as you said, but on Simulator it works perfectly as before. Just have longer loading times but works without crashing the app.

Comment: Ok then try enabling the "All Exceptions" as said by @Chitra, but keep the NSZombieEnabled checked, these are the simpler ways to tackle memory issues.

Comment: I suggested the above answer for debugging with device. You must test it by connecting the device, as its working fine on your simulator. Also check the Resource/Images path that you are using which is case sensitive on device and case insensitive on simulator.

Comment: I always take care of CS. Could it be that "Tests" Build problem?

Comment: Hey it really helped me out! Your answear and @Chitra Khatri (Breakpoints) helped me to find the Error. It was because of an ALLOC problem with an NSMutablearray getting Data from SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Exception Break point.. From there you will get idea where app crashes:

Here are steps for that:

[image]

Comment: i done this already! No Stops, No Breaks NOTHING... I just dont get it what there is wrong with that code... On Simulator it really doesnt crahs. Just on real iPad Device.

Comment: i suggest check this by connecting device